# Pivot table from column to row in excel or R

Tags: r, excel, pivot, reshape

I have a table with header like this

```
Id x.1960 x.1970 x.1980 x.1990 x.2000 y.1960 y.1970 y.1980 y.1990 y.2000
```

I want to pivot this table as

```
Id time x y
```

What is the best way to do this in Excel or R?

Comment: Please add reproducible sample for good people here to help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: you can use melt and cast functions from reshape package . Details [here](http://had.co.nz/reshape/introduction.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this using base R `reshape`:

Get some data first

```
test <- read.table(text="Id x.1960 x.1970 x.1980 x.1990 x.2000 y.1960 y.1970 y.1980 y.1990 y.2000
a 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
b 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100",header=TRUE)
```

Then reshape:

```
reshape(
  test,
  idvar="Id",
  varying=list(2:6,7:11),
  direction="long",
  v.names=c("x","y"),
  times=seq(1960,2000,10)
)
```

Or let `reshape` guess the names automatically based on the `.` separator:

```
reshape(
  test,
  idvar="Id",
  varying=-1,
  direction="long",
  sep="."
)
```

Resulting in:

```
       Id time  x   y
a.1960  a 1960  1   6
b.1960  b 1960 10  60
a.1970  a 1970  2   7
b.1970  b 1970 20  70
a.1980  a 1980  3   8
b.1980  b 1980 30  80
a.1990  a 1990  4   9
b.1990  b 1990 40  90
a.2000  a 2000  5  10
b.2000  b 2000 50 100
```